# How to list all directories except one?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, directory

I am writing a batch file where I need to list all the directories except those called "pdf".

This is a simple example of what I currently have, returning all directories:

```
for /r /d %%D in ("*") do (
        echo %%D
    )
```

Is there an equivalent to:

```
for /r /d %%D not in ("pdf") do (
        echo %%D
    )
```

When I try that I get the following output:

```
"not was unexpected at this time."  
C:\txt-in\for /r /d %D not in ("pdf") do (
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is probably

```
for /r /d %%D in ("*") do (
    if not "%%~nxD"=="pdf" (
    echo %%D
    )
)
```

Comment: Don't forget to use `%%~nxD` to include the entire folder name for folder names which contain a period.

Answer (score 4):

You are close with your first snippet.  Just add a `if` statement within the loop or change the loop to use the `dir` command with `find`.

Show folder names not "pdf"

```
for /r /d %%D in (*) do (
    if /i not "%%~nxD"=="pdf" (
        echo %%D
    )
)
```

Or show folder names not containing "pdf"

```
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /a:d /b ^| find /v /i "pdf"') do (
    echo %%D
)
```

The `/i` matches regardless of letter case.  Remove the `/i` to make the search case insensitive.